# SetWindowsHookEx sends multiple events

Tags: windows, xna, keyboard, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I'm using SetWindowsHookEx with C# to allow me to have buffered keyboard input (for a textbox).

The basic setup right now is that each time I create a new textbox, the textbox internally creates a new "KeyboardBuffer" object, which in turn sets up a keyboard hook:

```
    public KeyboardBuffer(IntPtr whnd)
    {
        this.ProcessMessagesCallback = new GetMsgProc(ProcessMessages);
        this.HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(HookId.WH_GETMESSAGE, this.ProcessMessagesCallback,
                                           IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
```

(full code can be seen [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/91491/548796.aspx#548796))

The issue is that if I have N textboxes, when I type in one textbox, I receive the same character N times, the issue stemming from the fact that SetWindowsHookEx doesn't discriminate between .NET instances.

I've temporarily fixed this by making a static KeyboardBuffer object that all textboxes access, but this has caused a host of other issues, and simply, in my opinion, seems hackish.

Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've thought about this more, and I've realized that I can remove/reset the hook when I disable/enable the buffer.  Is there any noticeable overhead with setting hooks?

Comment: You should hook only once.  Pay attention to the MSG you get in the callback.  It contains the handle of the window that will get the message.  Get the control reference with Control.FromHandle().  Do favor IMessageFilter instead btw.

Comment: In that case, is there any alternative to SetWindowsHookEx that would allow me to only forward messages to a specific .NET instance?